# assigning values in NSArrays

Tags: objective-c

Objective C gives me a run-time error for the indicated line of code

```
-(void) play: (int)i at: (int)j {
    if ([self.board[i][j] isEqualToString:@""]){
        if (xplays) {
            self.board[i][j] = @"x";   //<-----HERE
        }
        else
            self.board[i][j] = @"x";
    }
    xplays = !xplays;
}
```

`board` is a property. The error message is

> [__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7123120
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7123120'

Do I need to use C-arrays for this kind of assignment?

Answer (score 3):

You should be using an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: It took me ages to work out what the guy who edited my answer had actually done. All he did was to mark the method name as code. That is all he did. Then he voted down the answer. Is he improving the site, or making it worse?